Why the fetch gets failed even when I am using cors dependency?
Used just simple code which works properly fine as I have checked using localhost, but when I am trying to fetch the localhost from google console then the error is showing :

fetch('http://localhost:3500/'); Promise {} VM42:1
GET http://localhost:3500/ net::ERR_FAILED (anonymous) @ VM42:1 VM42:1
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
at :1:1

    const express = require("express")
const app = express();
const path = require("path");
const cors = require("cors")

const { logger } = require("./myMiddleware/logEvent");
const errorHandler  = require("./myMiddleware/errorHandler");

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3500;

//custom middleware
app.use(logger);

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/public")));

app.use('/subdir', require('./routes/subdir'))
app.use('/', require('./routes/root'));


app.all('*', (req, res)=> { // page not found
    res.status(404)
    console.log("Thank You")
    if(req.accepts("html")) {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "views", "404.html"));
    }else if(req.accepts("json")) {
        res.sendFile({ error : "404 not found"});
    }else {
        res.type("txt").send("404 not found");
    } 
});


// CUSTOM ERROR HANDLER
app.use(errorHandler);

app.listen(PORT, ()=> {
    console.log("Server running on port "+PORT); 
});



    



when I am trying to fetch the localhost from google console localhost refers to the server your app is running on and cannot be used from outside (it will refer to the machine that is making the request). So you are probably looking to change it to the public address of the machine you are trying to reach?

You seem to have SPA, so the problem is that you're actually serving 404 to fetch once the index.html is loaded.
The usual way for SPAs is to send index.html on each request for the SPA's router to handle it. Also, API routes handlers should be set before that (for fetch to handle users and other data).
Try this.
// setup API routes for frontend router (users, get data and other stuff..)
//app.use('/api', apiHandlers);

// serve SPA on all routes
app.get('/', (req, res)=> {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "views", "index.html"));
});

// handle error
app.use((err, req, res, next)=>{
    res.status(404).sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "views", "404.html"));
});


Thank you for it. But my friend the whole concept was I was trying to learn why CORS dependency is needed. So in order to check it first I need to know about the CORS error that's why I was fetching localhost from google console. I have used several routes but for easy to understand purpose I have added only one route (Now I have added the whole code). But even having all the separated routes while I am on google console still is showing : VM45:1  Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
at :1:1. I am facing this error even after installing CORS dependency.

doesn't seem to be cors issue. how are you running this page, is it on the same port, or is it on some dev server? did you try curl http://localhost:3500/

Yes I have tried with the same url & it works, it works totally fine. I am getting pages according to the routes. But when I am trying it in google console using : fetch('localhost:3500/'); , then that specific error is showing.

so frontend and backend are on the same port? how are you running it, try running "deployed/build" version, I'm not sure what else could be the problem..

Thanks a lot for your time my friend. I successfully solved this issue.
